# How can I pass an data from factory to my controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to move all the business logic from my controller to the factory, but I'm having some trouble passing **fields** data.

**factory.js**

```
app.factory("Quote", function ($resource) {
    // TODO: this shouldn't start with /en/
    var quoteStatus = [];
    var quoteLanguage = [];

    var Quote = $resource("/en/quote/api/quote/:id", {}, {
        retrieve: {
          method: 'GET',
          params: {},
          isArray: true
        },
        query: {
          method: 'GET',
          params: {},
          isArray: true,
          url: '/en/quote/api/quote/'           
        },
        fields: {
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/en/quote/api/quote/fields/ '
        },
        update: {
          method: 'PATCH',
        },
    });

    Quote.fields().$promise.then(function (fields) {
        var tempObj = [];
        for (key in fields.status) {
            // must create a temp object to set the key using a variable
            tempObj[key] = fields.status[key];
            quoteStatus.push({
                value: key,
                text: tempObj[key]
            });
        }

        for (key in fields.language) {
            // must create a temp object to set the key using a variable
            tempObj[key] = fields.language[key];
            quoteLanguage.push({
                value: key,
                text: tempObj[key]
            });
        }

        //$scope.addLanguage($scope.language);

        Quote.status = quoteStatus;
        Quote.language = quoteLanguage;
    });

    return Quote;


});
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.quoteStatus = Quote.status;
```

However this is not working since *$scope.quoteStatus* is **undefined**. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect async operation to behave in synchronous way.

Basically when controller inject `Quote` in its factory function that time `Quote` service object gets created  & then calls Quote.fields(). hen you ask `Quote.status` inside a controller will always return undefined. You are not maintaining promise anywhere so that controller will come to know that the data is ready or not.

I think you should introduce `$q.when` flag there to check the `Quote.fields()` operation completed or not & then do get the desired variable there.

For implementing above mention thing you need to store the promise of `Quote.fields()` call somewhere in service. like below

```
var quoteFieldsPromise = Quote.fields().$promise.then(function (fields) {

   /// the code will be same here

};
```

Then add new method which will hold of `quoteFieldsPromise` promise object and return the value of `quoteStatus` & `quoteLanguage`.

```
var getQuoteDetails = function(){
   $q.when(quoteFieldsPromise).then(function(){
      return { quoteStatus: Quote.quoteStatus, quoteLanguage: Quote.quoteLanguage };
   })
}
```

But the way you have returned whole `Quote` object, which only has `$resource` object which needs to be changed. I mean to say that the `getQuoteDetails` method which I've created can not be return with `Quote` object. So I'd rather rather refactor service to below.

**Service**

```
app.factory("Quote", function($resource, $q) {
    // TODO: this shouldn't start with /en/
    var quoteStatus = [], //kept private if needed
        quoteFieldsPromise, 
        quoteLanguage = [];//kept private if needed

    var QuoteApi = $resource("/en/quote/api/quote/:id", {}, {
        //inner code is as is 
    });

    //preserve promise of .fields() call
    quoteFieldsPromise = Quote.fields().$promise.then(function(fields) {
        //inner code is as is 
        //below lines are only changed.

        Quote.status = quoteStatus;
        Quote.language = quoteLanguage;
    });

    var getQuoteDetails = function() {
        return $q.when(quoteFieldsPromise).then(function() {
            return {
                quoteStatus: quoteStatus,
                quoteLanguage: quoteLanguage
            };
        })
    };

    return {
        QuoteApi: QuoteApi,
        getQuoteDetails: getQuoteDetails
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
Quote.getQuoteDetails().then(function(quoteDetails){
    $scope.quoteStatus = quoteDetails.quoteStatus;
    $scope.quoteStatus = quoteDetails.quoteLanguage;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj but how can I use `getQuoteDetails` in my controller? I've tried setting it like: `Quote.prototype.quoteFields = function(){}` in my factory.js but still appears undefined.

Comment: You helped me very much. Kindly appreciated.

Comment: @GustavoReyes Glad to hel you..Thanks.